# How to delete points from CSV point layer?

Tags: qgis, point

I have a point layer produced from importing a Delimited Text Layer and I would like to delete some points. It seems that it is not possible to toggle editing in a point layer. How can I delete the selected points?

(QGIS version 1.8.0-Lisboa)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to edit a point layer.  However, it is not possible to edit a layer that is created on the fly from delimited text.  Save your layer in some other GIS format (e.g. Shapefile - right-click on the layer and select 'Save As').  Then toggle editing on the new layer.